# DocumentFilter allowing only numbers and period (.) into JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, replaceall, documentfilter

\Here is the creation of the JTextField:

```
hourlyWageInput = new JTextField("7.25");
DocumentFilter filter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();
((AbstractDocument) hourlyWageInput.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
hourlyWageInput.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
add(hourlyWageInput);
```

Here is my DocumentFilter:

```
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

 public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
      String text, javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attr)

      throws BadLocationException {
           fb.insertString(offset, text.replaceAll("\\D", ""), attr);   
 }
}
```

This automatically removes all letters and characters from the JTextField.

However, I was wondering if anyone knows of a place with all of the commands similar to "\D". It took me a while to find the right information.

Also, the code I have now also prevents . from being types which I need as I am working with doubles. Any ideas?

Thanks! It's amazing how much I have learned today. I've been coding 13 hours straight.

Comment: Google tutorials on regular expressions. A starting point: [Oracle Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). My favorite: [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Start from the beginning as it's pretty intense stuff.

Comment: That's some funky code you have there. Generally you should call the matching method in `FilterBypass`, and you probably also want to override `insertString`.

Comment: @David Tunnell Thank you so much for this topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `replaceAll` function takes in a regular expression.  You can learn a bit about regular expressions from many tutorials online (see @Hovercraft Full Of Eels comment) or directly from the Java api:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Essentially you can put together any of the regular expression constructs (listed in the above link) together to form a regular expression.  If you for instance wanted to ensure that only 0-9 and . are allowed, you can use:

```
text.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "")
```

Comment: I will read the tutorials. Thanks for all of the info the program is working now.

Comment: I'm having trouble achieving a reliable `DocumentFilter` solution for similar problems. I need the input to follow a regex, but using a `replaceAll()` or similar (using `Matcher` to accumulate matches and remove non-matches) is rpoving painfully unreliable. --- For example, this answer's solution will go very bad as soon as the user inputs a second `'.'` in the `TextComponent`, as it breaks the decimal consistency.

Comment: @TheLima - your question is slightly different.  It'd be beneficial to post it as it's own question (with a reference here), that way I could give you a full answer.  But basically you want a more advanced Filter that senses whether the decimal has been used before.  Just put a boolean field in the DocumentFilter which determines if the regex used for validation allows the period or not.

Comment: @NickRippe - The link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610320/how-to-make-jtextfield-or-jformattedtextfield-accept-input-only-if-it-matches-a). My problem is related but not exactly the same as the decimal-point consistency, but it's something I *also* don't know how to do and that might help solve the problem. --- It might be a better idea to post the decimal-point consistency answer here as an edit, rather than there though.